# Join on tables (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am a newbie to SQL and i have a question here. I am working in Postgresql. 
My tables look like

**change**

```
     id action_id(fk)   field_id(fk)    old_value   new_value   
------------------------------------------------------------------
      39      15              14                           testPool
      40      15              15                           testSystem 
      41      15              16                           61019
```

**action**

```
     id  description       audited_table     audited_row      audited_type  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     15  Added system       systemtable        61019          insert
```

**field**

```
      id       audited_table                name    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      14       systemtable                 pool
      15       systemtable                 storagesystem
      15       systemtable                 id
```

I would want to write a query to get the following view

```
  id        description                  audited_table               audited_row      audited_type   field.name1     name1->new_value  field.name2     name2->new_value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  15        Added system                 systemtable                 61019              insert         pool            testPool        storagesystem    testSystem
```

Basically i want to flatten(rows into columns) the 'change' table and join it with 'action' table. Please note that **'Change'** table **references to 'action' and 'field'** tables

Schema diagram looks like below

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your question id contradictory in several places. dba.SE is a [`question and answer site for database professionals`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/about). I suppose you try your luck on stackexchange.com. But first read the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html) and get your question straight.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not completely clear what you are after, but let me attempt an answer.

First let's create the table and the example data:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/26bd9/13)

**PostgreSQL 9.1.9 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Change
    ("id" int, "action_id" int, "field_id" int, "old_value" varchar(10), "new_value" varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Change
    ("id", "action_id", "field_id", "old_value", "new_value")
VALUES
    (39, 15, 14,'', 'testPool'),
    (40, 15, 15,'', 'testSystem'),
    (41, 15, 16,'', '61019')
;

CREATE TABLE Action
    ("id" int, "description" varchar(12), "audited_table" varchar(11), "audited_row" int, "audited_type" varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO Action
    ("id", "description", "audited_table", "audited_row", "audited_type")
VALUES
    (15, 'Added system', 'systemtable', 61019, 'insert')
;

CREATE TABLE Field
    ("id" int, "audited_table" varchar(11), "name" varchar(13))
;

INSERT INTO Field
    ("id", "audited_table", "name")
VALUES
    (14, 'systemtable', 'pool'),
    (15, 'systemtable', 'storagesystem'),
    (15, 'systemtable', 'id')
;
```

If your question is about how to join the tables, the answer is fairly straight forward:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT C.id,
       A.description,
       F.audited_table,
       A.audited_row,
       A.audited_type,
       F.name AS field_name,
       C.new_value
  FROM Change AS C
  JOIN Action AS A
    ON C.action_id = A.id
  JOIN Field AS F
    ON C.field_id = F.id;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/26bd9/13/0)**:

```
| ID |  DESCRIPTION | AUDITED_TABLE | AUDITED_ROW | AUDITED_TYPE |    FIELD_NAME |  NEW_VALUE |
|----|--------------|---------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|------------|
| 39 | Added system |   systemtable |       61019 |       insert |          pool |   testPool |
| 40 | Added system |   systemtable |       61019 |       insert | storagesystem | testSystem |
| 40 | Added system |   systemtable |       61019 |       insert |            id | testSystem |
```

For more information about joins check out my blog series here: [sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/](http://sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/)
It is SQL Server based, but most of the information there is independent of the RDBMS you are using.

---

If you are trying to get multiple rows turned into one you are looking for a pivot.
You can execute a pivot by esentially grouping the rows together and then using a combination of `MAX()` and `CASE` to pick single values out. The problem with your question is that you do not specify what makes a field "field1" vs "field2". To solve this I added a numbering to the fields in order of the field_id using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. With that the first field is the field with the smallest field_id. The pivot now looks like this:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT action_id,
       audited_table,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 1 THEN name END) AS f1_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 1 THEN new_value END) AS f1_new_value,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 2 THEN name END) AS f2_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 2 THEN new_value END) AS f2_new_value
  FROM(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY C.action_id, F.audited_table ORDER BY F.id) field_number
      FROM Change AS C
      JOIN Field AS F
        ON C.field_id = F.id
    )X
 GROUP BY action_id, audited_table;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/26bd9/13/1)**:

```
| ACTION_ID | AUDITED_TABLE | F1_NAME | F1_NEW_VALUE | F2_NAME | F2_NEW_VALUE |
|-----------|---------------|---------|--------------|---------|--------------|
|        15 |   systemtable |    pool |     testPool |      id |   testSystem |
```

Query 2 just gets the information for the Field and Change tables. To also get the Action information we need to add another join:

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT A.id,
       A.description,
       X2.audited_table,
       A.audited_row,
       A.audited_type,
       X2.f1_name,
       X2.f1_new_value,
       X2.f2_name,
       X2.f2_new_value
  FROM Action AS A
  JOIN (
    SELECT action_id,
           audited_table,
           MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 1 THEN name END) AS f1_name,
           MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 1 THEN new_value END) AS f1_new_value,
           MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 2 THEN name END) AS f2_name,
           MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 2 THEN new_value END) AS f2_new_value
      FROM(
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY C.action_id, F.audited_table ORDER BY F.id) field_number
          FROM Change AS C
          JOIN Field AS F
            ON C.field_id = F.id
        )X1
     GROUP BY action_id, audited_table
  )X2  
  ON A.id = X2.action_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/26bd9/13/2)**:

```
| ID |  DESCRIPTION | AUDITED_TABLE | AUDITED_ROW | AUDITED_TYPE | F1_NAME | F1_NEW_VALUE | F2_NAME | F2_NEW_VALUE |
|----|--------------|---------------|-------------|--------------|---------|--------------|---------|--------------|
| 15 | Added system |   systemtable |       61019 |       insert |    pool |     testPool |      id |   testSystem |
```

I hope this answers your question.